# Timezone calculation in laravel application

Tags: database, laravel, timezone

There are a lot of Geo-device data in my database. The data is stored with the timestamp in UTC which is 5 hours 45 minutes behind in my laravel application.

I have configured the timezone to `'timezone' => 'Asia/Kathmandu',` in my `config/app.php` file.

Now, every time I insert the data I need to subtract the query with 5:45and add 5:45 while sending to the view. Is there any configuration or any other methods that can act as there is no lagging in time?

Comment: please provide your code when inserting the data and previewing the data

Comment: why don't you just create a helper? there can be a scenario people sending data from multiple countries helper would solve the issue.